# the sum function cannot work with string values

Tags: string, sum, powerbi, dax, percentage

I'm working with DAX in PowerBI. I hava a column with 80 000 string values.
70% of these values is "European Desk". I want to show this percentage. It's string value, i don't understand how to do it with DAX

Any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measure you are looking for is

```
% European Desk = DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(
        COUNT('Table'[String]),
        'Table'[String] = "European Desk"
    ),
    COUNT('Table'[String])
)
```

With CALCULATE you can change the filter context for the COUNT() aggregation.

You can apply this formula to e.g. this table:

```
Table = DATATABLE(
    "Index", INTEGER,
    "String", STRING,
    {
        {1, "European Desk"}, 
        {2, "European Desk"},
        {3, "European Desk"},
        {4, "African Desk"},
        {5, "Asian Desk"}
    }   
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i adapt your formule i got : 

% European Desk = DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(
        COUNT('Incident_6 mois'[assignment_group]),
        'Incident_6 mois'[assignment_group] = "European Desk"
    ),
    COUNT('Incident_6 mois'[assignment_group])
)

But the results is "1"

Comment: Try each element of the nested formula on its own to see what they deliver. Then put them together.

Comment: Check the formula with the above table. Maybe it'll help you to spot the issue with your data model.

Comment: I added a column when EUROPEAN SERVICE DESK = 1 and everything else is 0. Then i got this error : 

DAX comparison operations do not support the comparison of Integer values with text values. Use the value or format() function to convert one of the

I don't understand, i don't have text values in my column ? I also checked your edit but i don't know where to put the new formule and what it does ? In a new mesure ?

Comment: Anyway i found the error for this new calcul, the results is the same, "1"

Comment: After one more hour, if i transform "1" to %, i got the 70%. I hate PowerBI when i can't get any information about things like this... but anyway thanks for all your help